# Kara's bitmap picture

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, lateral-thinking

Kara recently received a puzzling bitmap image by email in the shape of a trapezoid. She didn't recognize the email address, and she doesn't know why she would be receiving such a picture. She attached the bitmap image below, and wants to know who it's from.

[image: Kara's bitmap image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If we

> first shear the top triangle rightwards...
>  [image]

and then

> shear the entire thing to line up the two vertical lines...
>  [image]

we can see that

> it's a note saying "**Date? -Jake**" -- looks like someone's asking her out!

Comment: Actually, the method I used was a little different. I started from the top-left corner of Jake's message and worked my way to the bottom right, starting with the first diagonal read from SW to NE, then the second diagonal, then the third, etc. Your method is a lot less time consuming! Well done!

Comment: Once you see it, you cannot unsee it in the original